# Use Python tkFileDialog to access network drive folders

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using Python `tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root, initialdir='\\\\Servername\\root\\cimv2')` to access a network drive folder, but am unable to do so.  A browse box with my computers drives opens up to select a folder.

Is there a way to select a folder from a network drive using Python?

Answer (score 1):

Your slashes should be reversed for the initialdir keyword argument.

It should be:

```
tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root, initialdir='//Servername/root/cimv2')
```

Answer (score 0):

[win32ui.CreateFileDialog](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pywin32/win32ui__CreateFileDialog_meth.html) might work for you. If you're on ArcGIS, the [`pythonaddins.OpenDialog` and `pythonaddins.SaveDialog` would work too](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//014p00000021000000).